# How can i open a pop window when i click on facebook link in my program?

Tags: python, webdriver

I have problem that when i click on facebook like it does not goes to window login popup?

Created on 03-Nov-2014

@author: thinksysuser
'''

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import unittest, time

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, NoAlertPresentException

class EcardsOp(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        self.base_url = "http://www.americangreetings.com/ecards/anniversary/flowers-and-hearts-4u/pn/3280122"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True


    def test_ecardsop(self):

        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/")  
        # switch to frame
        driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".fb_iframe_widget > span:nth-child(1) > iframe:nth-child(1)"))
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.pluginButton:nth-child(1)").click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException, e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True    


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, modification is required in your css for the button to get clicked. 
Please replace the code

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.pluginButton:nth-child(1)").click()
```

with

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.pluginButton:nth-child(1) button").click()
```